# Pytest: ModuleNotFoundError. Problem with my import statements

Tags: python, import, pytest

Initial development of my project had everything in the same directory and all of my Pytest tests worked fine.  I changed directory structure for packaging and moved code into `src/project_name` directory, and all test files into `test/`.  Now Pytest throws a ModuleNotFoundError.  I am running pytest from the test directory by calling `pytest`.  I run it from project root.  I run it with `python -m pytest`.  Same ModuleNotFoundError each way.

Current project structure is:

```
src
    project_name
        __init__.py
        moduleA.py
        modluleB.py
test
    testA.py
    testB.py
```

No matter how I write my import statements, I am getting the same error.  I have tried:

```
# testA.py

import src.project_name.moduleA
```

which throws an error that there is no module `src`.

```
# testA.py

import project_name.moduleA
```

This errors on `project_name`.
Finally:

```
# testA.py

import moduleA
```

This errors on `moduleA`.

There's something obvious I am missing, but can't figure it out.  How can I get my imports to work on my test.py files?

Comment: Is testA.py in a completely different folder than the project_name directory, or is test under the `src` directory?

Comment: @shoebob - src and test are at the same level.

Comment: `src` doesn't have an `__init__.py` file in it based on your photo

Comment: @gold_cy And it shouldn't have. The package is called `project_name`, not `src`.

Comment: the way this project is structured `src` is the top most level where imports are happening, so I disagree

Comment: The pytest documentation disagrees and "strongly suggests to use a `src` layout," without an `__init__.py` file in `src`: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#tests-outside-application-code

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on the type of configuration file you want to use, but here are a few options:
In general, you have to add `src` to your `PYTHON_PATH`.

```ini
# pyproject.toml
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
python_files = "test*.py"  # to discover testA.py and testB.py
pythonpath = "src"
```

```ini
# setup.cfg
[tool:pytest]
python_files = "test*.py"  # to discover testA.py and testB.py
pythonpath = "src"
```

```ini
# pytest.ini
[pytest]
python_files = "test*.py"  # to discover testA.py and testB.py
pythonpath = "src"
```

Some references:

- [configuration files](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/customize.html)
- [pythonpath option](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-pythonpath)

Comment: you shouldn't have to manually add the path if it is set up correctly

Comment: @gold_cy You are right, I've edited the answer.